# Multiple if else

Tags: php, if-statement

How can i show some default code only if BOTH if statements are false ?

I've got this code -

```
  <?php if( get_sub_field('cta_phone')): ?>
   <a class="phone" href="tel:<?php the_sub_field('cta_phone');?>"><?php the_sub_field('cta_phone');?></a></span>
<?php else: ?><?php endif; ?>

<?php if( get_sub_field('cta_mobile')): ?>
   <a class="phone" href="tel:<?php the_sub_field('cta_mobile');?>"><?php the_sub_field('cta_mobile');?></a></span>
<?php else: ?><?php endif; ?>

<?php else: ?>
   <img src="http://my-domain/image.jpg">
<?php endif; ?>
```

i'm not using the `else` bit at the end at the moment because i only want that to show if both 'if's are false ?

hope that it makes sense

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 php tag only to make your syntax much more readable and 
avoiding

multiple `<?php ?>` tags.

you can also use `echo` to print your `html` markup using `php` scripting like this.

```
<?php
if( get_sub_field('cta_phone')){
    echo '<a class="phone" href="tel:'.the_sub_field('cta_phone').'">'.the_sub_field('cta_phone').'</a></span>';
} else if (get_sub_field('cta_mobile')){
    echo '<a class="phone" href="tel:'.the_sub_field('cta_mobile').'">'.the_sub_field('cta_mobile').'</a></span>';
} else {
    //do what you want to do here, if they are false.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks , the 'else' works if neither of the if's are true , but if i have one that is true or both are true , it only displays the first entry but shows it twice ?

```
 <?php
if( get_sub_field('cta_phone')){
    echo '<a class="phone" href="tel:'.the_sub_field('cta_phone').'">'.the_sub_field('cta_phone').'</a>';
} else if (get_sub_field('cta_mobile')){
    echo '<a class="phone" href="tel:'.the_sub_field('cta_mobile').'">'.the_sub_field('cta_mobile').'</a>';
} else {
    echo '<img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">';
}
?>
```

Comment: if both statements are true (if and else if) then it will execute by precedence (meaning it will execute the first true "if"), "if's" can only execute one of the if's  at a time. it cannot execute multiple if's under one if-elseif-else tree.